# Destructure object on provided parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, destructor

I can't think of a way to destructure an object from provided argument:

```
type PossibleStateProperty = 'hello' | 'world'

type State = {
  hello: 'welcome',
  world: 'earth'
}

handleError = (name: PossibleStateProperty) => {
   const { [name] } = this.state
}
```

Where I would destructure the `state` object property based on the provided function argument.

```
const { [name] } = this.state
```

is sadly invalid

Comment: Destructuring can only extract variables that exist in an object, i.e. `const { hello, world } = this.state;`

Comment: Hi, can you clarify your example code? 

You are typing `name` param as `PossibleStateProperty` which is a string union type. If you want to destructure your state, follow @JDunken suggestion.

Comment: `const { [name]: value } = this.state` where `value` will be the variable available in that scope.

Comment: @EmileBergeron ooh yes, in the meantime I came up with `const value = this.state[name]`  but I prefer your suggested destruct syntax. Thanks for linking to the other question :)

Comment: Both are equally valid, I'd even say that destructuring is just overkill in this case, but most React app setup have the `prefer-destructuring` linting rule which prompts most dev to go with my suggestion above.

Comment: I do agree it is an overkill, but I'm destructuring other more standard state properties (which I excluded in my example for clarity), so it feels more natural to do it in one statement.